# Unimodularization of lattice by Kneser

Tags: lie-algebras, integer-lattices

Let $L$ be a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ corresponding to some root system (or Lie algebra, or Dyinkin diagram, etc...) I just learned that we can *unimodularize* $L$ by adding some shifted points. For example, the lattice corresponds to $A_{1}\oplus A_{1}$ is a lattice in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ generated by $v_{1}=(\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and $v_{2}=(0, \sqrt{2})$. Then this Lattice can be unimodularized by considering 
$$
L^{+} := L \cup \left(L + \frac{1}{2}(v_{1}+v_{2})\right).
$$
Then what is the corresponding process in the Lie algebra side (or root system or Dynkin diagram)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe this corresponds to some process / construction in the root system / Lie algebra, or is that an assumption or part of the question?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg There's no reason, but one of the audience asked this question to the lecturer but the lecturer didn't know the answer.